# Obtaining a given bound for an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $f:D(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be analytic, and assume that $Re(f(z)) > 0$ for all $z \in D(0,1)$ and $f(0)=1.$ Prove that for all $z \in D(0,1),$
$$|f(z)| \leq \frac{1+|z}{1-|z|}.$$

My approach: I considered the function $g(z)=\frac{1-z}{1+z} f(z)$ and tried to show that it's bounded by $1$ using the given information. But I wasn't successful. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You should compose your map $w=f(z)$ with $h:w\mapsto \frac{w-1}{w+1}$. Show that $h\circ f$ maps $D$ to $D$ and $0$ to $0$ and use a standard result (Schwarz Lemma) for such a map...

Comment: Thank you. Is there a criteria to use which map to use to compose with when using Schawarz lemma ? I know the composed map has to be from $D$ to $D$ and the origin maps to origin but having a hard time to figure out which map to use.

Comment: i@ManMath  It can be very hard. But If you are dealing with disks and half-spaces then it is (almost) always Möbius transformations. You then have to figure out the constants. In the present case $1$ should map to zero (whence the $w-1$ upstairs) and the imaginary axis should go to the unit circle so we should divide with something symmetric w.r.t. $i{\Bbb R}$whence a pole at -1. There is an overall factor of mod 1 which we still can choose.